# insert into one table selecting from another works slow. (Sybase)

Tags: insert, sybase

SYBASE

```
insert into table_1
select * from table_2
```

the query works very slow. Table_1 is empty but has a clustered index, table_2 has 70 mln rows, and 72 columns. 
Any suggestion?

Thanks,
Oleg

Comment: I would suggest you drop the clustered index on table 1 and re-add it after the table is loaded.  Everytime you insert a row, it has to write to the index as well..it slows things down.

Answer (score 0):

Define "very slow" How long does it take?What do you expect? 70 million rows, and how many columns? what size of columns?

Is the target table table_1 empty, or are there even more rows inside table_1?
 Does the target table have a primary key defined? How much RAM do you have, and what value does the the max_memory parameter have (= the amount of RAM that Sybase can actually use)?

If you just want to create a copy of the table, Run a select * into table_1 from table_2. You might need to enable the "allow select into" server-option.

Alternatively, create a clustered index on the target table `with ignore_dup_rows` option defined  and then run the  insert-into staement again. This will silently ignore all primary key violations.

Comment: table_1 does  ot have any records. It has clustered index. amount of columns is the same - 72. I expect time 1 min. It takes 30 mn. and still running.

Comment: ... with 70 million rows and that many columns it will take a very long time, unless you have gigantic amounts of RAM installed. Rework your table design. And please edit your question to provide more info from your comment to other experts who might not read all the comments.

Comment: I cannot change table design. I cannot delete any record from table_2, I am just trying to get all active records from table_2 to table 1. All amount of source table 70 mln, 3 mln are active. Any suggestion?

Comment: If you cannot change the table design, so you probably cannot change the server options and you cannot drop and recreate indexes. So run a SELECT statement with a highly selective WHERE clause and iterate this in a loop. (INSERT INTO table_1 select * from table_2 where table_2_pk between 1 and 1000) then (INSERT INTO table_1 select * from table_2 where table_2_pk between 1001 and 2000...) etc. You get the idea. Also takes a really long time as well, but you have more control over the copy process

Comment: If table_1 can't be changed, then he'll have to use `select * into existing table_1 from table_2`